# TortoiseSVN checkout deletes all my local code, then says "OK"

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visual-sourcesafe

I'm from a **Visual SourceSafe** background, so please bear with me.
I'm trying to achieve the **TortoiseSVN** paradigm shift.
By the way, I have **VisualSVN** but I did not use it to create this problem I'm having now.

One thing they all have in common is they all need a liberal helping of message boxes to the effect of "Hey, I'm about to blow away a ton of files from *location*. Is this ok?"

I'm working on code from work and from home. I'm the sole developer.
At the end of the work day at the office, I did a *Check In*, er, `Commit` on all changes I did during the day. That worked fine.

When I got home, All I wanted to do was the equivalent of a *Get* in VSS. I simply want to replace any local files with files from the repository that are updated. That's all. Nothing complicated I hope.

So I did an `Update` on my top level working folder (that word is directionally ambiguous, by the way). Which complainded that a bunch of files had conflicts. Note that I didn't want to merge, I want to over-write local with what's in repository. So now my shell overlay icons are, uh, were, all the colors of the rainbow.

So then I googled and read the answer was to do a `Check Out` and then a `Revert`.
So I did a checkout from the root folder in **Repository Browser** and TortoiseSVN proceeded to **delete** just about every file in my working directory! It then said **OK** like, mission accomplished, great, that's what you wanted, you betcha!

Ok so can anyone explain this in a way that will make sense to an old VSS user? I did not read the 200 page book (maybe my answer is on the 3rd paragraph of page 176), but I did google and there are plenty of hits on recovering files accidentally deleted by the user, but none on explaining the deleting behavior of TortoiseSVN.

**Summary:**

1. Why did it do that?
2. How can I just reliably do a *Get* when I get home from work?

Comment: You don't have to read the entire 200 page book. Read `Chapter 2 - Basic Usage`.

Comment: @Ken Ok, I read Chapter 2. Slowly. It said a checkout would put files into my working directory from the repository. It sure didn't mention deleting anything. Actually, nothing I've read so far explains that in the slightest bit. But thanks for the suggestion. Generally, reading all the instructions is a good standard procedure.

Comment: I'm a little confused about the problem you're having. I frequently check out files in one folder, make changes there, check them in, and then check them out into a different folder (like using one at home and one at work) without issue. I also frequently create branches locally, so that I can do something outlandish without worrying about it, and either desert the effort or merge it back into the trunk. It's a little unclear what problem you're having exactly; I've never had to do an update and then revert to accopmplish anything except fix a screwup I've made. Update-oops, not right--revert.

Comment: That makes two of us. ok, so when you check out, it has never resulted in the deletion of the local file. I guess my question isn't so stupid after all then. Cool.

Comment: This isn't an answer, but I deleted the .svn folder, did a checkout on the root working folder (from explorer), then did a revert on the root working folder to tell it "I don't care about local changes; make it like the repository". At that point everything is green. Any work-around that involves deleting the .svn isn't really a solution...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds to me that you may have got into the situation where your working copy is a Frankenstein mixture of a directory of files that pre-date your use of SVN and the 'proper' SVN working copy.  The fact that you had to do a checkout and then revert strikes me as strange because a checkout will always give you a clean working copy with no changed files. I suspect that you checked out into a non-empty directory, which isn't generally advised (there are circumstances where it can make sense to do this, but I don't think that is true in this case).

I think what you need to do is check out to a new directory.  You should then have a pristine working copy with no changes.  The checkout directory should be the name of the new directory that gets created. I suspect that you have deleted the last bit of the path in order to force the checkout into the current directory.  Here's a concrete example:

- The URL you want to checkout is `http://server/svn/trunk`
- You have a directory `c:\source` already that has other projects in it. In Explorer right-click and choose SVN Checkout.
- Enter the URL and in the directory field enter `c:\source\trunk`.  If you were to enter `c:\source` then SVN would try to merge the existing contents with those from the checkout, which is rarely what you want.

Once you have a pristine working copy you shouldn't get the surprises you're seeing. When you update you would only get conflicts is someone else had changed the file independently of you changing it yourself.  An update on a proper working copy would never trash any files you've created *unless* you've manually copied files into your working copy that have been added to SVN independently.

Comment: I do believe you are correct, sir. Last night I did delete the .svn folder to start over. If I continue to have problems when I get home tonight I will apply these steps. Thanks for the answer and explanation! See, VSS didn't care about dates doing an unconditional *Get*. SVN does look at the dates. I just **assumed** it worked the same way, kinda like Frankenstein **assumed** his monster would not be homicidal.